# SBT settings scoped to interactive mode?

Tags: scala, sbt

I wonder if it's possible to **scope SBT settings to interactive mode**.

This would be quite handy to set e.g. `-Xfatal-warnings`, depending on if SBT is run in batch mode (CI) or in interactive mode (incremental compilation during development). Sadly, `compileIncremental` doesn't work.

```
compileIncremental / scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot("-Xfatal-warnings".==)),
```